# set export variables for another bash call in piped code

Tags: bash

I a bash script which set variables with export and runs another bash to use a console with some password variables. It works ok, but now I want to encrypt the script, so I use openssh to encrypt it, and a wrapper to decrypt it and run.

decrypted code:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset HISTFILE
  export MYPASSWORD="*******"
/bin/bash
```

my wrapper is:

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script.crypted | bash -
```

I expect a console where I can access my variable.

Comment: What is the output of `openssl enc` command? What does it do? Where can be found the decrypted file? Did you check the documentation, maybe you can make `openssl enc` print the decrypted file onto stdout? What is your question?

Comment: ```openssl enc``` is used to encrypt or decrypt text. I use it in another script to run commands which use the password without problems (p.e. backup files). But when I try to open an _interactive_ console with variables set, it fails.

Comment: I create a script backup.sh which sets a variable, and backup my files. I create another script  console.sh which sets the password variable, and open a bash to execute commands having my password variable set (and it works). Now I try to encrypt my files, so I encrypt both files and set a wrapper to run them. The wrapper for backup works, but the one with the console don't. It seems ```bash``` process run after setting the variable ends immediately

Answer (score 0):

Finally I encrypted my whole home in the shared computer. An overkill but more secure.